# YouTube API Pause Triggered Prior to End on onStateChange function

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I am trying to make a YouTube video play in a loop silently. Then when the user clicks to pause, restart the video and play on full volume.

This is the approach I took.

```
var flag = 1;
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    var player;

    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
            playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'controls': 1,'autohide':1,'wmode':'opaque' },
            videoId: '[CODE]',
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,
            }
        });
    }

    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
        event.target.mute();
    }

    function onPlayerStateChange(event){
        //alert('State changing!');
        if (event.data == 0){
            alert('Play over');
            player = new YT.Player('player', {
                playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'controls': 1,'autohide':1,'wmode':'opaque' },
                videoId: '[CODE]',
                events: {
                    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,
                }
            });       
        }
        else if(event.data == 2)
        {   if(flag == 1)
            {
                alert('Play loud!');
                event.target.stopVideo(); 
                event.target.clearVideo(); 
                event.target.seekTo(0); 
                event.target.setVolume(100);
                flag = 4;
            }
        }
    }
```

My problem is that, when the video ends it triggers onPlayerStateChange with pause (`event.data == 2`) before it fires play end (`event.data == 0`).

Is this natural or is it just me. I don't find it sense that the 'Pause' to fire?

Have you taken a similar approach? Could I know what you did?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question, but a comment on your code: there's no need to create new `YT.Player` objects. You can just call methods like `loadVideo()` on your existing `YT.Player` object.

Answer (score 1):

Firing off a paused state before an ended state is pretty standard. It's been happening for as long as I can remember. It's not guaranteed to always stay that way, though.